# How to interpolate only between values (stopping before and after last NaN in a column) with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

If I have a `df` similar to this one:

```
print(df)
                       A  B  C    D    E
 DATE_TIME                               
2016-08-10 13:57:00  3.6  A  1  NaN  NaN
2016-08-10 13:58:00  4.7  A  1  4.5  NaN
2016-08-10 13:59:00  3.4  A  0  NaN  5.7
2016-08-10 14:00:00  3.5  A  0  NaN  NaN
2016-08-10 14:01:00  2.6  A  0  4.6  NaN
2016-08-10 14:02:00  4.8  A  0  NaN  4.3
2016-08-10 14:03:00  5.7  A  1  NaN  NaN
2016-08-10 14:04:00  5.5  A  1  5.7  NaN
2016-08-10 14:05:00  5.6  A  1  NaN  NaN
2016-08-10 14:06:00  7.8  A  1  NaN  5.2
2016-08-10 14:07:00  8.9  A  0  NaN  NaN
2016-08-10 14:08:00  3.6  A  0  NaN  NaN

print (df.dtypes)
A    float64
B     object
C      int64
D    float64
E    float64
dtype: object
```

Thanks to a lot of input from the community I have this code now which allows me to upsample my df to second intervals, applying different methods to different `dtypes`

```
int_cols = df.select_dtypes(['int64']).columns
index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq="s")
df2 = df.reindex(index)

for col in df2:
if col == int_cols.all(): 
    df2[col].ffill(inplace=True)
    df2[col] = df2[col].astype(int)
elif df2[col].dtype == float:
    df2[col].interpolate(inplace=True)
else:
    df2[col].ffill(inplace=True)
```

I am looking for a way now, to only interpolate between my actual measurements. The interpolate function extends my last measurement until the end of the `df`:

```
 df2.tail()
Out[75]: 
                            A  B  C    D    E
2016-08-10 14:07:56  3.953333  A  0  5.7  5.2
2016-08-10 14:07:57  3.865000  A  0  5.7  5.2
2016-08-10 14:07:58  3.776667  A  0  5.7  5.2
2016-08-10 14:07:59  3.688333  A  0  5.7  5.2
2016-08-10 14:08:00  3.600000  A  0  5.7  5.2
```

But I would like to stop this when the last measurement took place (for example at 14:04:00 `col['D']` and 14:06:00 `col['D']`) and leave the NaNs.

It tried adding a zero value for 'limit' and 'limit_direction' to 'both':

```
 for col in df2:
if col == int_cols.all(): 
    df2[col].ffill(inplace=True)
    df2[col] = df2[col].astype(int)
elif df2[col].dtype == float:
    df2[col].interpolate(inplace=True,limit=0, limit_direction='both')
else:
    df2[col].ffill(inplace=True)
```

but this didn't change anything to the output. I than tried to incorporate the solution I found to this question: [Pandas: interpolation where first and last data point in column is NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691591/pandas-interpolation-where-first-and-last-data-point-in-column-is-nan) into my code:

```
for col in df2:
if col == int_cols.all(): 
    df2[col].ffill(inplace=True)
    df2[col] = df2[col].astype(int)
elif df2[col].dtype == float:
   df2[col].loc[df2[col].first_valid_index(): df2[col].last_valid_index()]=df2[col].loc[df2[col].first_valid_index(): df2[col].last_valid_index()].astype(float).interpolate(inplace=True)
else:
    df2[col].ffill(inplace=True)
```

...but that did not work and my `float64` columns are purely NaNs now...Also, the way I tried to insert the code, I know it would only have affected the `float` columns. In an ideal solution I would hope to do the set this `first_valid_index():.last_valid_index()` selection also to the `object` and `int64` columns. Can somebody help me? ..thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close! Here's an example to get the point across that's very similar to the code you posted toward the end of your post:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, 4.0, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 0.0, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan]},
                  columns=['A', 'B'], 
                  index=pd.date_range(start='2016-08-10 13:50:00', periods=7, freq='S'))
print df

A_first = df['A'].first_valid_index()
A_last = df['A'].last_valid_index()
df.loc[A_first:A_last, 'A'] = df.loc[A_first:A_last, 'A'].interpolate()

B_first = df['B'].first_valid_index()
B_last = df['B'].last_valid_index()
df.loc[B_first:B_last, 'B'] = df.loc[B_first:B_last, 'B'].interpolate()

print df
```

result:

```
                       A    B
2016-08-10 13:50:00  NaN  NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:01  1.0  NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:02  NaN  0.0
2016-08-10 13:50:03  NaN  NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:04  4.0  NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:05  NaN  2.0
2016-08-10 13:50:06  NaN  NaN

                       A         B
2016-08-10 13:50:00  NaN       NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:01  1.0       NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:02  2.0  0.000000
2016-08-10 13:50:03  3.0  0.666667
2016-08-10 13:50:04  4.0  1.333333
2016-08-10 13:50:05  NaN  2.000000
2016-08-10 13:50:06  NaN       NaN
```

The two problems in your code were:

1. If you are going to do `df[...] = df[...].interpolate()`, you need to
   remove `inplace=True` since that will make it return `None`. That is your main problem and why you were getting all `NaNs`.
2. Though it seems to work here, in general, chained indexing is bad:

You want:

```
df.loc[A_first:A_last, 'A'] = df.loc[A_first:A_last, 'A'].interpolate()
```

Not:

```
df['A'].loc[A_first:A_last] = df['A'].loc[A_first:A_last].interpolate()
```

See here for more detail: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations and the helpful link. I tried following line `df.loc[df['A'].first_valid_index():df['A'].last_valid_index()] = df.loc[df['A'].first_valid_index():df['A'].last_valid_index()].interpolate()` with your `df` to see what it would do and I was surprised that also column B changed. Why would that happen? I also changed the line from my code: `df2.loc[df2[col].first_valid_index():df2[col].last_valid_index()] = df2.loc[df[col].first_valid_index():df2[col].last_valid_index()].interpolate()`, which still wont work. Sorry for asking again, I am really trying to learn

Comment: It's changing column B too because you didn't specify a column, so it's interpolating every column.  Generically, what you need is `df.loc[<slice of rows>, <column>] = df.loc[<slice of rows>, <column>]`.  Specifically, what you need is `df.loc[df['A'].first_valid_index():df['A'].last_valid_index(‌​), 'A'] = df.loc[df['A'].first_valid_index():df['A'].last_valid_index(‌​), 'A'].interpolate()` and `df2.loc[df2[col].first_valid_index():df2[col].last_valid_ind‌​ex(), col] = df2.loc[df[col].first_valid_index():df2[col].last_valid_inde‌​x(), col].interpolate()`

Comment: Thank you! It is working now! I am bewildered though, that when I run this line (where I modified the one in the original answer)  `df.loc[df['A'].first_valid_index():df['A'].last_valid_index(), 'A'] = df.loc[df['A'].first_valid_index():df['A'].last_valid_index(), 'A'].interpolate()` it works, but with this seemingly exact same line `df.loc[df['A'].first_valid_index():df['A'].last_valid_index(‌​‌​), 'A'] = df.loc[df['A'].first_valid_index():df['A'].last_valid_index(‌​‌​), 'A'].interpolate()` as a copy-past from your last edit I get `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier.` Am I crazy?

Comment: Weird, maybe some invisible character got in there during copying and pasting?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14844830/5405967

Comment: indeed....i copied in into notepad and it is `last_valid_index(??)` vs. `last_valid_index(??????)`....thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

For pandas `0.23.0` is possible use parameter [`limit_area`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#dataframe-interpolate-has-gained-the-limit-area-kwarg) in [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, 4.0, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 0.0, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan]},
                  columns=['A', 'B'], 
                  index=pd.date_range(start='2016-08-10 13:50:00', periods=7, freq='S'))
print (df)
                       A    B
2016-08-10 13:50:00  NaN  NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:01  1.0  NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:02  NaN  0.0
2016-08-10 13:50:03  NaN  NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:04  4.0  NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:05  NaN  2.0
2016-08-10 13:50:06  NaN  NaN

df = df.interpolate(limit_direction='both', limit_area='inside')
print (df)
                       A         B
2016-08-10 13:50:00  NaN       NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:01  1.0       NaN
2016-08-10 13:50:02  2.0  0.000000
2016-08-10 13:50:03  3.0  0.666667
2016-08-10 13:50:04  4.0  1.333333
2016-08-10 13:50:05  NaN  2.000000
2016-08-10 13:50:06  NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can backfill null values and then use boolean indexing to take the null values of each column (which must be the tail nulls).

```
for col in ['D', 'E']:
    idx = df[df[col].bfill().isnull()].index
    df[col].ffill(inplace=True)
    df.loc[idx, col] = None
```

Comment: thank you! I am still trying to understand how to use it! I understand what it should be doing I think but I m not quite there yet..